# Why did scrollbars changed in Firefox?

Tags: firefox, design, scrollbar

Since the dawn of windowed software, to click on the scrollbar space (i.e. not the arrows, nor the small block) meant to scroll the size of one page (just like pressing Page Up/Page Down).

Now, in a recent update, not only is Firefox missing the scrollbar arrows, but also when I click somewhere in the scrollbar makes the small block go to that position. Probably somebody somewhere thought it was a "nice" innovation, but I think it's just completely useless. If I want to go with the small block to a new position, all I needed to do was grab the block and drag it there. I can't shift my window by the size of one page anymore. Of course I can still use the Page Up/Page Down keys, but they won't work for horizontal scrollbars.

Any way to revert this? Or at least let the developer in question know that we're not satisfied with their "need for useless innovation"?

I'm using Firefox 46 on Ubuntu 14.04.

Comment: if you go into the customization you can check to see if any other themes are available .. maybe it kept the old one and you can switch back or maybe you can download the old one through  "more themes"

Comment: In the linked answer I found that I can scroll the old way using the right mouse button. That will be enough for me. Thanks!

Comment: also in Firefox you can use the arrow keys to scroll up/down/left/right

Comment: I only wonder why they have this URGE to change things that were very well defined for at least 20 years!